# Node js view and api server share the constants

Tags: node.js, vue.js, koa

Got a problem while practising `Nodejs` with `koa2` and `vue-cli`.
For example `vue` send a password verification request to `koa`, and the `koa` may give the different error info like `wrong password` or `user not found`.
then `vue` shows error info under `username <input/>` or `password <input/>` based on the error info.

So I think should create `constants.js` for both `vue` and `koa` using, to define these errors. Just like `enum` in C++ header file.

Koa:

```
ctx.body = {
  success: false,
  info: 'user not found'
}
```

Vue:

```
if (!res.data.success) {
  if(res.data.info == 'user not found'){
    showErrorAtName(res.data.info)
  } else if(res.data.info == 'wrong password') {
    showErrorAtPW(res.data.info)
  }
}
```

Question: Is this idea right?

Comment: Why don't you just return the error message to be displayed in the koa response ?

Comment: @Varkal I did return it, for example, login failed may need to display the message under the username or password base on the message. So the message is used by both view and API side, shall I created a file for the global defines and let view and API share it.

Comment: I've never done this. I always let the backend manage error message, and send it all data required to construct it. Only one exception : an "Unexpected Error" message for when the backend is down. You don't want to redeploy both frontend and backend for just a typo in a message, and you don't want user put them in cache.